# java for-each loop for partial array

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, partial

I know how to use the for-each loop to cycle through an entire array like so:

```
for(int d : arrayname){
    do something
```

But how do you use the for-each loop to cycle through a partial array, like the one I am trying to do is to use the for-each to cycle through only the months of May-October, i.e. [4] - [9] to calculate the heat index. Here is a snippet of my code that shows what I am trying to do:

```
// create array for KeyWestTemp
    double[] KeyWestTemp;
    KeyWestTemp = new double[12];

    // initialize array
    KeyWestTemp[0] = 70.3;
    KeyWestTemp[1] = 70.8;
    KeyWestTemp[2] = 73.8;
    KeyWestTemp[3] = 77.0;
    KeyWestTemp[4] = 80.7;
    KeyWestTemp[5] = 83.4;
    KeyWestTemp[6] = 84.5;
    KeyWestTemp[7] = 84.4;
    KeyWestTemp[8] = 83.4;
    KeyWestTemp[9] = 80.2;
    KeyWestTemp[10] = 76.3;
    KeyWestTemp[11] = 72.0;

    // create array for KeyWestHumid
    int[] KeyWestHumid;
    KeyWestHumid = new int[12];

    // initialize array
    KeyWestHumid[0] = 69;
    KeyWestHumid[1] = 67;
    KeyWestHumid[2] = 66;
    KeyWestHumid[3] = 64;
    KeyWestHumid[4] = 66;
    KeyWestHumid[5] = 69;
    KeyWestHumid[6] = 67;
    KeyWestHumid[7] = 67;
    KeyWestHumid[8] = 70;
    KeyWestHumid[9] = 69;
    KeyWestHumid[10] = 69;
    KeyWestHumid[11] = 70;

    // for-each loop for calculating heat index of May - October
```

[0] is January and [11] is December

Comment: You use a for loop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double[] mayOctober = Arrays.copyOfRange(KeyWestHumid, 4, 9);
```

and foreach mayOctober to do what you asked.

btw, it is prefered in that case to use conventional loop.

Comment: This feels like a hack, whereas a traditional for loop can achieve this directly

Comment: but OP asked for a foreach, not a combentional for loop ;)

Comment: You are technically correct, to the letter of the question you are right. I hope this isn't what they really wanted, but it is what they asked for

Comment: I may (not admitting anything) have down voted this answer, if you feel like editing it (trivial edit, just to unlock) I might remove it (if it ever existed)

Answer (score 5):

You are using the enhanced for loop, you can just use the regular for loop to achieve what you want

```
for(int i=START; i<=END;i++){
     //do work
}
```

In your case it would most likely look like

```
int sumOfHumidity=0
for(int month i=4; i<=9;i++){
     sumOfHumidity+=KeyWestHumid[month]
}
```

and then use `sumOfHumidity` however you see fit.

#### Other notes

- `KeyWestHumid` is a variable, as such it should be lowerCamelCase, so
  `keyWestHumid`, the same for `keyWestTemp`
- The hard coding of 4 and 9 is probably undesirable, but without knowing the exact program structure it is hard to advise further than saying using the variables `startMonth` and `endMonth` is probably desirable, allowing `numberOfMonths` to be calculated using the two (which I expect you'll want to create an average from `sumOfHumidity`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a normal for loop:

```
for(int month=4; month<=9; month++){
 KeyWestHumid[month].something();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the enhanced for loop to partially iterate an array.
According to the Java language specification:

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of
>   the form:
>
> ```
> T[] #a = Expression;
> L1: L2: ... Lm:
> for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
>     VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
>     Statement
> }
> ```

You can, as suggested in other answers, either create a new array (or any other collection) which contains only the elements you want to iterate or use a regular for loop.

Comment: drorb - I thought that the Enhanced For requires the class implements Iterator. How is a full array able to use the Enhanced For?

Comment: The type of the Expression must be Iterable or an array type, or a compile-time error occurs. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

```
double[] array = {1, 6, 7, 3, 3, 1, 2, 8, 9, 7, 3};

Arrays.stream(array, 3, 6).forEach((d) -> {
    System.out.println(d);
});

OR

IntStream.range(3, 6).mapToDouble(i -> array[i]).forEach(d -> {
    System.out.println(d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting away from arrays and use `List`s.

```
public void test() {
  List<Double> keyWestTemp = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(70.3, 70.8, 73.8, 77.0, 80.7, 83.4, 84.5, 84.4, 83.4, 80.2, 76.3, 72.0));
  System.out.println("Key West Temps: "+keyWestTemp);
  System.out.println("Apr-Jun Temps: "+keyWestTemp.subList(3, 6));
  keyWestTemp.set(4, 81.6);
  System.out.println("Apr-Jun Temps: "+keyWestTemp.subList(3, 6));
}
```

Obviously you can iterate across the sub-lists as easily as you can print them and they shine-through to the underlying list. i.e. if you change the original list the sub-list also sees the change.